# list in list in BEM

Tags: css, css-selectors, bem

I understood `block__element--modifier` naming rule with BEM methodology.
But how can I name this kind of structure? If you have an nested list in outer list.
How can I name nested `ul` and `li` in `list` block with `list__item` element?

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        <ul>    
    <li class="list__item"></li>
    <li class="list__item"></li> 
</ul>
```

**Update** (as Dan Rocha's answer)

"Are you talking this?"

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item">
        <ul class="list--inner>
            <li class="list__item--inner></li>
            <li class="list__item--inner></li>
        <ul>    
    <li class="list__item"></li>
    <li class="list__item"></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nested list should look just the same you can use the same naming for it. And if it's different consider using modifiers/mixes or even absolutely new names (if inner list styling has nothing in common with parent).

Comment: It sounds make sense. Can you confirm my updated question?

Comment: I'd go for nesting in updated case: `.list--inner .list__item { /* some styles */ }`

Comment: If inner list item styling has nothing in common with parent then I can use `list__item--inner` ?

Comment: sure. but that will result in as many additional classes as many items inner list has which is not always handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `list--inner` and modify the `list__item` inside of it if needed